# How to make the first picture of the site. There are different lazy loading effects on different devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make our website faster, so I need to make the image lazy loading. If I let all the pictures lazy loading, the first screen image on the pc side will block, so I need the first screen image on the pc side not lazy loading, and the mobile side lazy loading. My website is a responsive website based on bootstrap, what should I do
I tried to use the js control class name to achieve, no effect

```
<img class="lazyload" data-src="real-image.jpg" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="图片描述">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // 检测是否为移动设备
  const isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

  if (isMobile) {
    // 使用IntersectionObserver实现懒加载
    if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            const img = entry.target;
            const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');
            img.setAttribute('src', src);
            observer.unobserve(img);
          }
        });
      });

      document.querySelectorAll('.lazyload').forEach(img => {
        observer.observe(img);
      });
    }
  } else {
    // PC端，直接加载图片
    document.querySelectorAll('.lazyload').forEach(img => {
      const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');
      img.setAttribute('src', src);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Optimizing your images will also decrease loading times.